# Odd line is being added on HTML table on print

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a table implemented with  and  tags.
I have border collapse, but when I try to print, odd lines are being added on page breaks.

The table is defined as following - `<table style="border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: -1px; text-align: center;font-size: 24px; white-space: nowrap; width: auto; min-width: 60px; padding: 0 20px;">`

I also have the following style tag -

```
<style>@page {size:auto; margin: 8mm;} @media print {html, body {height: 99%;}} body{margin: 1mm 1mm 1mm 1mm;} table, td, th {  border: 1px solid black;text-align: center ;}table {border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%;} td {padding: 3px;}</style>
```

Please see the following image for reference -

[image]

Is there any way to avoid this added line?

Edit -
Here's an example to help reproduce the issue;
When printed and is more than one page, the lines appear.

```
<html dir="rtl">
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <div style="direction:rtl; font-size: 24px; font-weight: normal">
         <br>
         <style>@page {size:auto; margin: 8mm;} @media print {html, body {height: 99%;}} body{margin: 1mm 1mm 1mm 1mm;} table, td, th {  border: 1px solid black;text-align: center ;}table {border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%;} td {padding: 3px;}</style>
         <table style="border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: -1px; text-align: center;font-size: 24px; white-space: nowrap; width: auto; min-width: 60px; padding: 0 20px;">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th style="font-weight: bold;border: 2px solid black; font-size: 24px;">A</th>
                  <th style="font-weight: bold;border: 2px solid black; font-size: 24px;">C</th>
                  <th style="font-weight: bold;border: 2px solid black; font-size: 24px;">B</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr style="border-top: 20px solid black">
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr style="border-top: 20px solid black">
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
                  <td>content</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here's how the example renders for me on Chrome-
[image]

Comment: My guess is that is is something to so with styles that are not being changed in your css for print, but it's difficult to tell what is happening without seeing the problem and the relevant code. It would  help if you could create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see it happening.

Comment: @FluffyKitten - Hey, I have added a reproducible example of the HTML. Opening that as a webpage and attempting print should reproduce. I'm using latest Chrome.

Comment: This code works for me. It must be some other CSS that the print CSS is not overriding?

Comment: @FluffyKitten it works for you when you attempt to print and it exceeds one page? (you can change the scale if it's less than one page)

Comment: Yes, it goes to 2 pages, but there is no line in the page break. What are you using to print it? Are you printing a physical copy or to file?

Comment: The default.
Ctrl + P from Chrome

Comment: @FluffyKitten I have just added another picture that shows how the print popup looks like, you can see the line in the end of page 1

Comment: Sorry... I was wrong :( I'm using Chrome too but I didn't see it at the zoom level the print preview opened at. If I zoom in or out I can see it.  When I zoom in I can see it. The only thing I can work out is that it is the top border from the table on page 2, but it doesn't matter if you set it only on the `table`,  `thead` or `th` and `td` - it still appears on the previous page. (I changed the colours of each of these to see which it was, and its all of them) I've nothing else... Sorry!

Comment: @Thanks for trying! Lets see if someone else could help out on this